# ManifestStaticFilesStorage Internal Server Error

Tags: django, caching, versioning, internal-server-error, wagtail

I'm trying to get static file versioning/caching up and running on my Wagtail site by way of `ManifestStaticFilesStorage`. When I upload to my stage server I get an `Internal Server Error`. Any idea what may be happening?

My base.py is my base settings, and stage.py is my stage settings. The traceback is included below as well.

**base.py**

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'assets'),
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**stage.py**

```
DEBUG = False

STATIC_ROOT = '/data/web/stage.sitename.com/web/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

**Traceback:**

```
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py” in get_exception_response

98.             response = callback(request, **dict(param_dict, exception=exception))
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.70.0.51/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py” in wrapper

503.                 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py” in _wrapped_view

149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/defaults.py” in page_not_found

45.         body = template.render(context, request)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py” in render

66.             return self.template.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render

208.                     return self._render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.70.0.51/newrelic/api/function_trace.py” in dynamic_wrapper

98.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in _render

199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render

994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render_annotated

961.             return self.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py” in render

174.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.70.0.51/newrelic/api/function_trace.py” in dynamic_wrapper

98.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in _render

199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render

994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render_annotated

961.             return self.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py” in render

210.                 return template.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render

210.                 return self._render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.70.0.51/newrelic/api/function_trace.py” in dynamic_wrapper

98.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in _render

199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render

994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py” in render_annotated

961.             return self.render(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py” in render

104.         url = self.url(context)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py” in url

101.         return self.handle_simple(path)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py” in handle_simple

114.             return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py” in url

132.                 hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py” in stored_name

292.             cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))
File “/data/virtualenv/sitename/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py” in hashed_name

95.                                  (clean_name, self))
Exception Type: ValueError at /favicon.ico Exception Value: The file ‘build/img/favicon.ico’ could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7fee94178190>. Request information: USER: AnonymousUser
```

Answer (score 5):

The error is because of the setting

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

If we use it the production the we have to make sure that every static asset that we use in the project should be available. If we miss any asset then we get the error `Missing staticfiles manifest entry`.

## How to fix the error ?

To fix the error first set `DEBUG=False` in `settings.py` after run the following command.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput
```

After execution of the above command it will show the manifest errors. Try to fix the errors and run the command again. Repeat the same until it runs successfully without throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a python manage.py collectstatic before rendering your page?

Comment: I had not set the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting on stage, so it didn't know which folder to grab the assets from when running collectstatic.